While gulp serve and gulp bundle getting the webpack error
I am trying to gulp serve my webpart but ending up with webpack issue.
Error - [webpack] Error processing webpack stats: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJson' of undefined
Error - [webpack] Webpack error: TypeError: localizedPath.startsWith is not a function

I have spfx 1.17.4 and node 14.19.1 gulp@4.0.2, i also tried to update node but seems like "nvm" is not recognized.
package.json
"@fluentui/react": "^7.199.1",
    "@fluentui/react-components": "^9.55.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base": "^1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.17.4",
    "@pnp/sp": "^3.26.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.199.1",
    "pnp-react-hooks": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "swiper": "^9.3.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"

logs
 eslint version: 8.7.0
 Starting subtask 'tsc'...
 [tsc] typescript version: 4.5.5
  Request: '/temp/manifests.js'
 Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 9.92 s
 Finished subtask 'tsc' after 15 s
 Finished subtask 'lint' after 20 s
 Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
 Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 578 μs
 Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
  Request: '/dist/CarouselWebPartStrings_en-us.js'
  Request: '/dist/carousel-web-part.js'
 Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 17 s
 Starting subtask 'webpack'...
  Request: '/dist/welcome-light_1eaf582a9b78272e22113e1e733138b8.png'
  Request: '/dist/welcome-light_1eaf582a9b78272e22113e1e733138b8.png'
Error - [webpack] Error processing webpack stats: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJson' of undefined
 Error - [webpack] Webpack error: TypeError: localizedPath.startsWith is not a function
 Finished subtask 'webpack' after 7.68 s


I guess you may have to install node v16.13+. See this compatibility matrix: https://tahoeninja.blog/posts/spfx-compatibility-matrix/

It looks like even after installing node v16.13.0 getting the same error message when gulp bundle --ship
Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@microsoft/sp-loader@1.18.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.17.1 <19.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

Downgrade @microsoft/sp-loader package to 1.17.4 using npm install @microsoft/sp-loader@1.17.4

Yes even after Downgrade same issue. I have installed node 16.13.0 looks like issue not solved with this version.

I think this issue is with the pnp-react-hooks 1.3.0, would downgrade of this will help to bundle ?

I suggest you to share your package.json and log details(after your gulp serve) to see which dependencies are installed in your solution.

Yes updated the main question, added the package.json and logs

I have solved this issue by updating the spfx to 1.20.0 and node to 18.18.2

Glad it resolved. Please add this as the answer and accept it so it will help others going forward.

You will need to update your node version to v16.13+. As the document shows the SPFx development environment


I have solved this issue by updating the spfx to 1.20.0 and node to 18.18.2
